# Getting warning of Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am using `prepare` method with Update Query

```
$updatequery = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE `".$table_name_sms."` SET sftemplate_name = '".$message."',sftemplate_type = '".$sfact_order_action."',sftemplate_status = '".$someSwitchOption001."' where sfID='".$_REQUEST['setid']."'") or die("yes not working"); 
                     $results = $wpdb->get_results( $updatequery , ARRAY_A );
```

and it is working fine but it also shows me warning of `Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()`

i also have checked the past answers but all question is using insert or select query no one is using it with Update query

Comment: some people are 170 cm high, some 169 and some 171, but no one is 170.5 so how can I trust their solutions will apply to me? :(. Please try those solutions you learned about in the other questions, and if you still can't figure how to solve this, edit question and add the information about what you have tried.

Comment: Read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

Comment: What i have tried i have mentioned in this question already

Comment: Actually i don't know how to use the `%s` and `%d`

Comment: ok, so why are you using prepare at all?

Comment: Actually i was not using before but somebody suggest me to use prepare for security so i am using it now

Comment: This is placeholders, `%s` is string and `%d` is integer values

Comment: Oh ok @PieterGoosen so am i using query right? or i have to add something else?

Comment: @JayantRawat, so maybe the question you should ask is about what prepare is used for, or the original question for which you got the suggestion.... As a rule for life I personaly don't use API before I completely understand (or think I do) what it does and all of its parameters

Comment: My question was why i am getting this warning is my script ok or i am forgetting anything else to insert on this query'

Comment: because, as the error states, you need to pass second parameter. We can not guess what it should be as we don't know the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `prepare()` statement is completely wrong. `prepare()` statements should be written in the style of [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). You have to pass two arguments (*for `prepare()` it became compulsary as of version 3.5*), if you pass only one, you get the missing arguments warning that you currently get. It will be beneficial if you look at how `sprintf()` works as this will help you alot here.

The purpose of `WPDB::prepare()` is to sanitize variable values passed to your statement in order to [prevent SQL injection](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks). This is extremely important. Hackers love to inject malicious code into form fields and URL's in order to try to get access to your site, and if you use unsanitized values from `$_POST` and `$_GET` and save that to db, you save that malicious code with your values in db, and boom, your site is open to the hacker.

A rule of thumb, if any data is coming from outside, ie any user submitted data (*and that includes you aswell*), never ever trust it. Always treat such data as infected and malicious. Never ever even trust yourself as well. **SANITIZE, VALIDATE AND ESCAPE** all data accordingly.

In your prepare statement, you should remove all your variables, and replace them with the corresponding placeholder. Again, please read and understand the `sprintf()` function page. You cannot mix placeholders, the placeholder passed will determine the sanitation which will be used on the value of the variable. If your variable is suppose to be string, use `%s` as placeholder, if the value is an integer, use `%d`. I'm not going to go into this, as it is pure PHP, so be sure to go and read up on using placeholders and `sprintf()`.

Just as an example, you can rewrite your statement as follow: (*UNTESTED*)

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "
        UPDATE %s 
        SET sftemplate_name = %s, sftemplate_type = %s, sftemplate_status = %s 
        WHERE sfID = %d
    ",
    $table_name_sms,
    $message,
    $sfact_order_action,
    $someSwitchOption001,
    $_REQUEST['setid']
)
```

### A FEW NOTES

- I think that using a variable to hold the table name is unnecessary, hardcode that.
- I accepted that all vlaues, except the last should be a string, the last value is an integer
- The above is just an example and is by no means a working example. You should first make sure that you understand how everything works before trying something on a live site

### EDIT

If you do not fully understand prepare statements, why not just use [`WPDB::update()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) It is much easier, faster from initial testing, and it automatically takes care of sanitation and validation as it uses `prepare()` before updating the db

Comment: Thanks for your information in such detail now i am quite understanding what it this for and how to use it. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped. Don't forget to accept my answer in order to mark this as resolved ;-)

Comment: Yes sure i did it :)

Comment: can you please answer me of my another question [here you can see](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218483/how-to-delete-more-than-one-table-while-uninstalling-plugin?noredirect=1#comment319844_218483)